# jQuery - isEmptyObject not picking up empty object

Tags: jquery, facebook

so I'm doing a Facebook graph APi call to receive likes of a photo, and as some of the photos have no likes, the object gets returned as empty.

I've got an example response here:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

My call is:

```
$.get(likesURL, function(data) {

}
```

I am doing a simple if statement to check whether it is empty but it is not picking it up.

```
if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                console.log("empty");
            }
```

I've also tried doing data.data etc but nothing catches it. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Your object is not empty.  It contains a property named "data".  An "empty" object must not have any enumerable properties.

Comment: I've tried using !data.hasOwnproperty(data.data) etc but nothing works? to see if it does not have data.data but nothing works?

Comment: Start by doing a `console.log(data)` to see exactly what you really have.  What are you trying to actually detect?  If you just want to know if there is anything in the data array, you can do this:  `if (data.data && data.data.length)` will tell you if there's anything in there.

Comment: use `data.length` condition in if

Comment: I'm trying to detect whether it does NOT has a property called "name" inside the data object, so then I can call a specific function. Okay thanks I'll get the size of array and see what it produces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do the following change it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get(likesURL, function(data) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(data.data)) {
            alert("empty");
        }
    });
});
```